# iterating through nested collections to create table with Angular ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, nested

I'm learning Angular and came across some difficulty when creating table from nested collection.
I simplified a bit my data and table for this example. Please help ;)

Here is what I want to achieve (note continent and country can span across multiple columns):

```
Continent: |               Europe            |   Asia   |
Country:   |          UK         |   Spain   |  China   |
City:      | Edinburgh |  London | Barcelona | Beijing  |
Population:|   500000  | 9000000 | 15000000  | 22000000 |
```

Here is data structure:

```
function playerCtrl($scope) {

$scope.continents = [
{
    "continent": "Europe",
    "columnSpan": 3,
    "countries": [
        {
            "country": "UK",
            "columnSpan": 2,
            "cities": [
                {
                    "city": "Edinburgh",
                    "info": [
                        {"population": 500000}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "city": "London",
                    "info": [
                        {"population": 9000000}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "country": "Spain",
            "columnSpan": 1,
            "cities": [
                {
                    "city": "Barcelona",
                    "info": [
                        {"population": 15000000}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "continent": "Asia",
    "columnSpan": 1,
    "countries": [
        {
            "country": "China",
            "columnSpan": 1,
            "cities": [
                {
                    "city": "Beijing",
                    "info": [
                        {"population": 22000000}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
    ];

}
```

Here is what I have so far for HTML (continents row is easy, struggling with rest):

```
<div ng-app>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- Player section -->
    <div class="col-sm-8" ng-controller="playerCtrl">
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
          <th>Continent:</th>
          <td ng-repeat="continent in continents" colspan="{{continent.columnSpan}}">{{continent.continent}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Country:</th>
          <td ng-repeat="country in continents.countries" colspan="{{country.columnSpan}}">{{country.country}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>City:</th>
          <td ng-repeat="city in country.cieties in continents.countries">{{city.city}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Population:</th>
          <td ng-repeat="city in country.cieties in continents.countries">{{city.info.population}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Link to jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/7on62750/

Comment: posted solution, however it feels a bit hacky and inefficient... still open for better solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little help of a friend I managed to solve this!

solution was to create functions that get me sub-collections.
Feels a bit hacky so feel free to post better solutions.

JS:

```
function GetCountries(continents) {
    var cuntries = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < continents.length; i++) {
        var a = continents[i];
       cuntries = cuntries.concat(a.countries);
    }
    return cuntries;
}

$scope.GetCountries = function(continents) {
    return GetCountries(continents);
}

$scope.GetCities = function(continents) {
    var countries = GetCountries(continents);
    var cities = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
        var a = countries[i];
       cities = cities.concat(a.cities);
    }
    return cities;
}
```

Html:

```
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
          <th>Continent:</th>
          <td ng-repeat="continent in continents" colspan="{{continent.columnSpan}}">{{continent.continent}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Country:</th>
          <td ng-repeat="country in GetCountries(continents)" colspan="{{country.columnSpan}}">{{country.country}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>City:</th>
          <td ng-repeat="city in GetCities(continents)">{{city.city}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Population:</th>
          <td ng-repeat="city in GetCities(continents)">{{city.info[0].population}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2guo5p6d/

Comment: since nobody posted better solution I accept this one